# How to instance mat-option values in angular tests

Tags: angular, testing, angular-material

I am trying to test my function but the forEach loop doesnt works. The problem is that this.selectNombre.options is undefined. How can I instance it?

My code:

```js
describe('StatisticsComponent', () => {
    let component: any;
    let element: any;
    let fixture: any;

    const optionSelect = [{
        label: 'prueba',
        type: 'option',
        value: 'value',
        selected: true,
    },
    {
        label: 'prueba',
        type: 'option',
        value: 'value',
        selected: false
    }];
```

```js
public optionNombreClick() {

        let newStatus = true;
        this.selectNombre.options.forEach((item: MatOption) => {
            if (!item.selected) {
                newStatus = false;
            }
        });
        this.allNombreSelected = newStatus;
}
```

My test:

```js
it('option nombre click', () => {
        component.allNombreSelected = false;
        component.selectNombre.options = optionSelect;
        fixture.detectChanges();
        component.optionNombreClick();

        expect(component.allNombreSelected).toEqual(false);
    });
```

variable optionSelect in test is an array of objects.

Thanks!

Comment: where do you init `optionSelect` value ? Does `component.selectNombre` already exists ? Also, `fixture.detectChanges()` seems irrelevent here, since you don't need to trigger the ngOnChanges.

Comment: @Random I init optionSelect in the first describe of the test with component and fixture.

Comment: can you edit your question to show that code ?

Comment: @Random Yep, done

Comment: ok, and where do you init `component.selectNombre` then ?

Comment: @Random i dont init, only in this test

Comment: So that may be the issue. if `component.selectNombre` is `undefined`, you cannot do `component.selectNombre.options = xxx`. Can you try `component.selectNombre = {options: optionSelect};` ?

Comment: So in the console, you should have seen an error on your UT line `component.selectNombre.options = optionSelect;`, saying something like "cannot set 'option' on undefined"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

component.selectNombre is actually undefined in your unit test, so you cannot set its `options` property.

do this instead:

`component.selectNombre = {options: optionSelect};`